# I could not get photos from flickr

Tags: android, android-viewpager, flickr

I have the following code in my FlickrFetcher I dont know what the problem is the log cat keep on giving me the following error.

04-12 13:38:49.351 29910-29923/com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery I/FlickrFetcher: Received JSON: {"stat":"fail","code":100,"message":"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"}
04-12 13:38:49.351 29910-29923/com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery E/FlickrFetcher: Failed to parse JSON: org.json.JSONException: No value for photos

the code  as followows

```
public class FlickrFetcher {

    private static final String TAG = "FlickrFetcher";

    private static final String API_KEY = "SECRET_KEY_HERE";

    public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage() + ": with " + urlSpec);
            }

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.close();
            return out.toByteArray();
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public String getUrlString(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        return new String(getUrlBytes(urlSpec));
    }

    public List<GalleryItem> fetchItems() {

        List<GalleryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String url = Uri.parse("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("method", "flickr.photos.getRecent")
                    .appendQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
                    .appendQueryParameter("format", "json")
                    .appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback", "1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("extras", "url_s")
                    .build().toString();

            String jsonString = null;

            jsonString = getUrlString(url);
            Log.i(TAG, "Received JSON: " + jsonString);
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            parseItems(items, jsonBody);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch: " + e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON: " + e);
        }

        return items;
    }

    public void parseItems(List<GalleryItem> items, JSONObject jsonBody) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject photosJSONObject = jsonBody.getJSONObject("photos");
        JSONArray photosJSONArray = photosJSONObject.getJSONArray("photo");

        for (int i = 0; i < photosJSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject photoJSONObject = photosJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem();
            item.setId(photoJSONObject.getString("id"));
            item.setCaption(photoJSONObject.getString("title"));

            if (!photoJSONObject.has("url_s")) {
                continue;
            }
            item.setUrl(photoJSONObject.getString("url_s"));
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
```

can any one expaline how I can modify this error thank you in advance

Comment: You *are* replacing SECRET_KEY_HERE by your actual API key right?

Comment: Please replace `SECRET_KEY_HERE` with your api key after you get one here : https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from the error message: `"message":"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"`

You're not putting in your API key properly.

```
private static final String API_KEY = "SECRET_KEY_HERE";
```

Your issue is here. You didn't replace `SECRET_KEY_HERE` by your actual secret key. You have to do that, duh!

You can get your key from this link:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html

> API Keys
>   To use the Flickr API you need to have an application key. We use this to track API usage.
>
> Currently, commercial use of the API is allowed only with prior
>   permission. Requests for API keys intended for commercial use are
>   reviewed by staff. If your project is personal, artistic, free or
>   otherwise non-commercial please don't request a commercial key. If
>   your project is commercial, please provide sufficient detail to help
>   us decide. Thanks!
>
> Apply for your key online now, and please make sure you include a
>   brief explanation of how you're planning to use it.

Apparently you have to ask for an API key, so do that!